# VBnet: Reference a form object from a class

Tags: vb.net, forms, class

**plan**

im sure this question must have been answered somewhere because its pretty basic, but unfortunately I havent found the answer ...

My plan is to create a simple log function that uses a RichTextField as an output and implements functionalities like Add, AddLine, RemoveLine, ReplaceLine, ...

**what doesnt work**

whenever i try to access the RichTextBox object from within the log Class, i get a "is nothing" exception.

**my approach**

the idea was to store a reference to the RichTextBox in the class itsself, that is passed on creating a new class instance:

```
Public Class Log
    Dim _logBox As RichTextBox

    Public Sub New(ByRef logBox As RichTextBox)
        _logBox = logBox
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddLine(ByVal text As String)
        Me.Add(text)
        _logBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And in my Form class, a RichTextBox is created at startup and passed to the log Class:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim log As New Log(RtbxLog) ' RtbxLog: RichTextBox object created on form

    [on some button click event]
      log.AddLine("entry with new line")  ' THIS CAUSES "nothing" EXCEPTION
End Class
```

Comment: what is RtbxLog?

Comment: Thats the RichTextBox element used for the log. Updated question.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! However, please don't put it into your question as doing so makes it harder to find, and it doesn't actually belong there :). The question should only contain _the actual question_ and the information necessary to reproduce the problem. If you want to show others how you solved the problem you are very welcome to post your own answer as well, in addition to the_lotus's! (Just don't forget to accept his/hers :)

Comment: Couldnt accept before, as i had to wait some time first, but thats done now. Hm i always add the solution i chose to the questions once they were answered, so people find everything in one place :P

Comment: Yeah, it's not that uncommon, but it should preferably not be done as it defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow's Q&A system. Even answers that aren't marked as the accepted one can still be of value.

Comment: Here's a small discussion on the topic: [Should I edit my question or post a new answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216719)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RtbxLog isn't initialized until the New is called. This is usually done during InitializeComponent(). I suggest you create your log after InitializeComponent is called (in the new).

Also, might I suggest you create your own control (that inherit from RichTextBox) instead. Or an other option is that your log class only store the information and the form takes care of display it in the textbox.

Comment: thanks! this was the reason. Moved the instance creation of Log Class to Form.OnLoad.