# How to change the value of a referenced variable stored in class?

Tags: vb.net, reference

So basically what I want to do is to store a reference to a boolean value in my class.

It looks something like this:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Private boolRef As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByRef inBoolRef As Boolean)
        boolRef = inBoolRef 'Assign reference of "inBoolRef" to "boolRef"
    End Sub

    Public Sub changeBool()
        boolRef = true 'Change value of the referenced boolean variable (outside of this class)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The object of that class is running in a parallel thread, and that's why I want the object to control the variable in its own thread.
And with my program doing this:

```
Module Program
    Dim myBool As Boolean = false

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim tC As New TestClass(myBool)
        'Opens a parallel thread in which the object does things
        'and should change "myBool" to true when the object is terminated
    End Sub
End Module
```

What I don't get is, that I declare a Boolean variable. Then I want another, in my Class saved variable to reference that variable (which was input in the ctor). 
In `boolRef = inBoolRef` I handle boolRef as if it was an actual reference.
But in `boolRef = true` in `changeBool()` it seems as if it's not a reference anymore.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206783/vbnet-reference-a-form-object-from-a-class) question shows me, that it is possible in VB.Net and also works, at least with objects.
But I can't assign different values to the `myBool` through means of the other instantiated object, which should store a reference to the variable. I mean, I could theoretically do something in the class like

```
Public Sub changeBool()
    boolRef.doSomethingLikeAssignAValue()
End Sub
```

but that won't work, because as far as I know, the `Boolean` is a primitive data type, and thus can not be changed by any `Sub`s.

I come from the C(++) world and there I find it way more intuitive on how to handle references, pointers, etc.

---

**TL;DR:**

What I wan't to do is basically this (in C(++)):

```
Class BoolChanger
{
Private:
    bool *boolRef = nullptr;

Public:
    inline BoolChanger(bool *inBoolRef)
    {
        boolRef = inBoolRef;
    }

    inline void change()
    {
        *boolRef = true; // Change value of pointed-to boolean variable
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool myBool = false;

    // Open parallel thread in which the object runs an does its things
    BoolChanger bc(&myBool);
    // ... and when it's done, it should set myBool to "true"

    return 0;
}
```

but in VB.Net. Please can someone help me? I seem to be missing something which is important to know...

Comment: The Boolean data type is a value type and not a reference type. See [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types&ved=2ahUKEwiWgO7i1-XnAhXD34UKHX2QBtgQFjABegQIChAH&usg=AOvVaw27zUO-lWJdFVJ5PMFqSZLX&cshid=1582392697578)

Comment: This isn't what we do in object oriented languages. Object A in Thread 1 doesn't have some sort of quantum entanglement relationship with Object B on Thread 2 whereby A changing the state if one of its own properties causes the state of a property in B to change; the whole thing reeks of terrible design in an OO sense; classes don't fiddle with each others private parts. If you want A to do some work and let the world/interested third parties/B know when it's done, use an Event on A that B can subscribe to

Comment: Or use a Task Parallel/async await that returns a bool, and have the await state machine sit around and kill time until your class is finished what it's doing, then continue from where it left off. In the mean-while the app will go back to whatever it was doing (drawing the UI, calculating Pi etc)

Comment: Well, the problem I face is that those are windows forms. When I create a new form an show it, it automatically opens up a new thread (or something similar?) and the code continues to run (at least in VB.Net, as far as I am concerned). I need the newly opened form to control the parameter so that I can return types, etc. So should I update the question for my more specific case? It's quite a lot of code, that's why I wanted to formulate it in more general terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the parameter to the method directly instead of *trying to* assign it to a Boolean value first. Like this:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Private boolRef As Boolean

    Public Sub New()   
    End Sub

    Public Sub changeBool(ByRef inBoolRef As Boolean)
        inBoolRef = true
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then use I like this

```
Module Program
    Dim myBool As Boolean = false

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim tC As New TestClass
        tC.changeBool(myBool)
    End Sub
End Module
```

I don't know if there was a reason you didn't do it this way previously. Please let me know if your program does not support this way :)

Comment: Ah, unfortunately that won't work because then the main flow of my program would change the boolean. But thanks to your answer I found a flaw in my original quesition, and thus I can update it. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the question. Basically why I can't do it was because the object instanciated with the reference is running in a parralel thread and needs to control it in it's own thread. I also updated the code a bit. Thank you and sorry for the confusion!